# Checked exception catching in C#

Tags: c#, exception

Java requires that you catch all possible exceptions or declare them as thrown in the method signature.  This isn't the case with C# but I still feel that it is a good practice to catch all exceptions.  Does anybody know of a tool which can process a C# project and point out places where an exception is thrown but not caught?

Comment: Why would you want to catch all exceptions? Unless you can do something to either correct the problem or you are logging it (in which case you would re-throw it afterwards), you should let exceptions bubble up to the point in code where they can be taken care of.

Comment: That said, I do think such a tool would be useful, but not for the *exact* same purpose you mention.

Comment: Well that is just it, I have no idea what exceptions might bubble up.  I could catch Exception but what am I going to do with that?  Being explicit about exceptions makes you think more about what you're writing and where it could go wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the ExceptionFinder plug-in by Jason Bock for the .NET Reflector.  It does just what you are looking for.  Here's a screeny:

Check it out on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/ExFinderReflector)

Answer (score 3):

There is a R# plug-in that analyses thrown exceptions.
http://exceptionalplugin.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Red-Gate software has a product called Exception Hunter which should do that.

**Edit:** This product has been discontinued by Red-Gate software.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# for a web application then you can use ELMAH which shows a list of all the handled and unhandled exceptions.

Just download ELMAH and plug it in. It is FREE!

Answer (score 0):

Don't catch them in individual methods, unless you need to, setup a global handler.

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler( Application_ThreadException );

private static void Application_ThreadException( object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{ 
       dispatchException( e.Exception );
}
```