# Unhandled Exception checker plugin for Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, plugins, exception

I would like to be able, at compile time, to ask any given method what possible Exceptions might get thrown by invoking it. The list of Exceptions should include any uncaught Exception that might get thrown in any nested method invokation.
Caught Exceptions should not be included in the list as I'm only interested in the Exceptions that might bubble up to my own code.

Does a plug-in for Visual Studio with that feature or something similar exist?

It would be great if this plug-in were also able to assist in the documentation of my code.

**Edit:**

Similar question: [Checked exception catching in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232318/checked-exception-catching-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just found the site, it's [Red-Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) that has a tool called [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/Exception_Hunter/index.htm), which pretty much does this.

**Not right:**
I am fairly certain one of the [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/) products includes a plugin that can do (something like?) this.

Comment: Note that if you need to do any profiling their memory and performance profiler products are also highly recommended... I used the free trial of one once to find a sticky problem in my code. If I had the spare cash I'd buy them for all my projects, but as-is I cannot justify the cost myself ;)

Comment: Redgate's exception hunter has been discontinued.