# Visual Studio: Code analyzer to determine what exceptions a method can throw?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, code-analysis

One nice thing about Java, which was also a curse, is that you always knew what exceptions a method could throw.

Is there a static code analysis tool that can determine what exceptions a method can throw?

> It would be great to be able to type `///` and have the xml documentation declaration section fill in the `<exceptions>` block automatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Does Visual Studio 2008 have a tool to show which Exceptions could be raised by a piece of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241070/c-does-visual-studio-2008-have-a-tool-to-show-which-exceptions-could-be-raised)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Resharper, you can use this plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/agentjohnsonplugin/