# find all exceptions occuring

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2012

I have a large .net application written in C#. I want to check if and what exceptions may be firing in the application that are caught by a try/catch and may not be evident - they are smuggled as such.

Anyway to find such easily? Any setting in visual studio for it?

Comment: Do you own source code?

Comment: Is it web application or WinForms/WPF?

Comment: web application and yes own code

Comment: [How to: Break When an Exception is Thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359465/visual-studio-code-analyzer-to-determine-what-exceptions-a-method-can-throw

Comment: Are you looking to find all cases where a method catches an exception and doesn't rethrow it?  Are you looking for a comprehensive list of all the exceptions that your code paths may throw?  May trigger?  It's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Debug / Exceptions` menu, and there you can register for exceptions (just check the exceptions you want to monitor).

This way, the debugger will break when they are raised, even if they should be caught later on.