# C# explicitly defining what exceptions are thrown

Tags: c#, exception, interface

In Java, you explicitly define what exceptions are thrown using the "throws" keyword. That way, anyone calling your method knows what to catch.

Is there something in C#? If not, how do I know what exceptions to catch, or how do I let others know what exceptions to catch?

Also, if I am defining an interface, is there a way to say "methodX() should throw this exception on error"?

Comment: I imagine the version of the .NET framework will make a difference here, but in the versions I use the answer is: you document potential exceptions well, and no - no way to force the type of exception thrown (short of trapping all exceptions outside, and re-wrapping them into your preferred type).  It's not just the exceptions you might generate in-method, there's also any you're letting bubble.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is nothing equivalent in C#: [The Trouble with Checked Exceptions](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html)

Other than documentation, there is no way to declare an interface to say "methodX() should throw this exception on error".

Comment: @dbkk: His objections are for the most part fallacious.  For instance he complains that you can't throw new types of exceptions in an implementation without changing the API, so old client code cannot call it.  This is true, but desirable.  If you throw new exceptions, the API has changed whether the exceptions are explicitly specified in it or not. Personally I'd rather have the client break horribly and spectacularly as soon as it tries to use the API than fail in subtle ways further down the line thanks to my not handling all the exceptions.

Comment: @JeremyP, I would rather spend time doing task that are **proven** to reduce bugs, like code reviews and writing more tests. Checked exceptions have never been shown to stop a worthwhile number of bugs, given there costs in programming time.

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: Handling error conditions properly is proven to reduce bugs.  Having a well defined explicit API is proven to reduce bugs.  Ignoring exceptions is not.

Comment: @JeramyP, but you should write your code to check that the operation is valid **before** doing it, so exceptions should not be common.

Comment: Ian Ringrose, LSP in SOLID is very clear about this. Method suggested by @JeramyP is my preferred solution. 'Adaptive Code via C#' is a great book that explains how you should deal with this problem, and its flow own effects to the rest of the solution and other implementations. If I wanted to add new exceptions without changing the API, I would try to extend a currently used exception. 
[Liskov Substitution Principle, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and 
[Adaptive Code via C#](http://www.amazon.com/Adaptive-Code-via-principles-Developer/dp/0735683204)

Answer (score 14):

C#/.net does not have checked Exceptions, they proved to be less useful in large scale systems than first thought.  In a lot of projects the time to maintain the check exception specs was a lot greater than the debugging time saved by having them.

Checked Exceptions seem like a good ideal until you have methods that can take delegates or calls into object you pass in.     Take a simple case, the Sort() method on a list can’t know what exceptions it will throw, as it does not know what exceptions the Compar() method on the objects being sorted will throw.

So the spec for the exceptions a method may throw must be able to include information on how exceptions are populated from pass in objects and delegates.   **No one knows how to do this!**

**However there are tools that you check if you are catching all exceptions – see Exception Hunter by Red Gate.  I personally don’t see much value in these tool, however if you like checked exceptions you may find them useful.** ==> Looks like Exception Hunter wasn't too useful, so [Redgate discontinued Exception Hunter a long while ago](https://documentation.red-gate.com/rp/exception-hunter):

Answer (score 10):

This feature is not available in C#. You can make proper XML documentation (3 slashes ///) and state what exceptions are being thrown.

This will be picked up by the IntelliSense mechanism and will be visible for the users of the class/method before they use it.

Answer (score 3):

C# does not support this. (Not that I know anyway).
What you can do is use Xml Comments so that while calling you methods this data will be shown by intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there is no throws declaration in C# you can document your method indicating that it throws an exception but no forced error handling.

Comment: lol time it took me to write this 2 others have already been posted!

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't support checked exceptions. The language designers consider checked exceptions in the way java uses them a bad idea.

[Some workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232318/checked-exception-catching-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Let me cite this medium article: [It's almost 2020 and yet... Checked exceptions are still a thing](https://ohadshai.medium.com/its-almost-2020-and-yet-checked-exceptions-are-still-a-thing-bfaa24c8997e)

Among the many reasons why it's a bad idea, putting the checked exceptions in the contract (interfaces):

1. makes it impossible to change the implementation of an interface with a different one which throws different exceptions
2. exposes implementation details
3. a change of the checked exceptions of an API interface, makes it necessary to change the whole chain of interfaces in the call stack

For example, imagine that you are implementing a repository based on SQL Server, so you expose all kind of SQL Server specific exceptions. Then you want to move it to MySQL or Cosmos BD. Of course:

1. the implementation can't be changed to a new one that need to throw different exceptions. Also related to this, if you have different implementations of the storage, you can't just change them by configuration, but you need to have different compilations of the code for each storage backend
2. this is the explanation for 1: as the interface showed the implementation details (SQL Server exceptions, now you can't just change it
3. if you need to make the change, prepare to change the interface at all levels, since the API that uses the database up to the latest consumer in the call stack chain.

The articles cited above includes pointers to many explanations to discourage the use of checked exceptions, included this by the creator of C#: [The trouble with checked exceptions](https://www.artima.com/articles/the-trouble-with-checked-exceptions)