# Forcing interface implementation to check for exception

Tags: c#, java, .net, exception, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# explicitly defining what exceptions are thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088114/c-sharp-explicitly-defining-what-exceptions-are-thrown)

I have a piece of Java code like this:

```
public interface ByteSource
{
    public void open() throws IOException;
    public void close();
    public byte readByte() throws IOException;
    public void writeBytes(byte[] bytes) throws IOException;
}
```

I am no Java expert (nor .NET one!) and I want to make a similar interface for `.NET` but I am not sure what to do about `throws ....`. I would like to know what does this means in Java language.

Should I care about it? At the moment the best thing (Or only thing I can think of) will be look like:

```
public interface IByteSource
{
    void Open();
    void Close();
    byte ReadByte();
    void WriteBytes(byte[] bytes);
}
```

Is there an approach in .NET similar to the java code?! Maybe some attributes ?!

Comment: C# also has System.IO.IOException: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx

Comment: +1 for updating your naming convention when porting to C#

Comment: Actually ReSharper did that :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't care about it. Checked exceptions were not added to .NET for lots of reasons, but basically because in most cases they are more of a hindrance than a help. You could perhaps use `///` to *document* the things it might be *reasonably expected* to throw, but leave it up to the call-chain to decide whether they handle that specifically. For example:

```
/// <summary>what this does</summary>
/// <exception cref="System.IO.IOException">some scenario</exception>
void Open();
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# you don't have to declare which exceptions your code throws, so just forget about this line of code. Your code is fine.